# Expressão Regular não funciona corretamente em webform

Tags: asp.net, regex, webforms

tenho o seguinte campo e validador em WebForm ASP.NET

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_Senha" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Senha" TextMode="Password" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_Senha" ValidationExpression="(?=.{8,})[a-zA-Z]+[^a-zA-Z]+|[^a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]+" ErrorMessage="A senha deve conter:<BR> * Mínimo 8 dígitos;<BR>* Números;<BR>* Letras MAIUSCULAS e minusculas" ForeColor="Red" />
```

Ao testar a expressão regular em:
http://ferramentas.lymas.com.br/regexp/regexp_br.php

Funciona bem,porém na pagina ela não aceita a senha:

```
1q2w3e4f5t6y7u8i
```

Acredito que seja porque não tem Maiuscula?
Mas aceita a senha:

```
quadros2014
```

e `quadros2014a` não aceita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro usar `^(?=.{8,})(?=.+[a-z])(?=.+[A-Z])(?=.+\d).+$`

Ou seja:

- `(?=.{8,})` para garantir 8 caracteres.
- `(?=.+[a-z])` para garantir pelo menos um caractere de letra pequena.
- `(?=.+[A-Z])` para garantir pelo menos um caractere de letra grande.
- `(?=.+\d)` para garantir pelo menos um caractere que seja um dígito.

Comment: Você pode por o `(?i)` para ignorar maiúsculo ou minusculo,
assim resumindo um pouco `^(?i)(?=.{8,})(?=.+[a-z])(?=.+\d).+$`

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert eu acho que o AP quer mesmo distinguir maiúsculo/minusculo. As nossas repostas diferem aí. O AP irá dizer qual é a que pretende.

Comment: Só uma dúvida Sergio, notei que essa expressão pede 2 Maiusculas, sendo que uma só já seria suficiente...

Comment: @Dorathoto a expressão aceita duas ou mais maiúsculas mas tem de ter pelo menos 1.

Comment: @Sergio mas pelo visto em meu código ela esta precisando de 2 maiúsculas para liberar o acesso. se a expressão regular esta correta vou verificar o que mais pode ser..

Comment: no site https://www.regex101.com/ disse que quando a maiúscula é a primeira letra ele não valida.

Comment: @Dorathoto repara na ultima letra (maiuscula): https://www.regex101.com/r/iF8vZ6/1 dá match. E com letra pequena não dá, https://www.regex101.com/r/eQ0yH5/1, diz "Your pattern does not match the subject string.".

Comment: a senha: Mac456789a não valida, mesmo tendo uma maiuscula..
https://www.regex101.com/r/eQ0yH5/2

Answer (score 2):

#### Situacao

A razão pela qual a senha `1q2w3e4f5t6y7u8i` não esta funcionando é a seguinte, em sua ER você tem:

```
(?=.{8,})    // ate aqui ok, você limitou a ter pelo menos 8 caracteres
[a-zA-Z]+    // uma ou mais quantidades de letras (alpha)
[^a-zA-Z]+   // qualquer coisa que não seja alpha, ou seja, ate mesmo estes caracteres "&¨#%"
```

validações:

```
stake%     // OK
stake4¨%   // OK
alpha!-=   // OK
casa¿@     // OK
casa$%dele // falso, pois tem 'dele' (alpha), apos [^a-zA-Z]+ (qualquer coisa exceto alpha)
```

apos você tem um `|`, ou seja outra possível validação:

```
(?=.{8,})    // ate aqui ok, você limitou a ter pelo menos 8 caracteres
[^a-zA-Z]+   // qualquer coisa que não seja alpha, ou seja, ate mesmo estes caracteres "&¨#%"
[a-zA-Z]+    // uma ou mais quantidades de letras (alpha)
```

validações:

```
%$#stake    // OK
@#$¨CASA    // OK
!varchar    // OK
teste3      // falso, pois inicio com 'teste' (alpha), primeira validacao [^a-zA-Z]+ (qualquer coisa exceto alpha)
```

#### Sugestão

Para validar senhas `alnum` utilize:

```
(?=.{8,})[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

validações:

```
1q2w3e4f5t6y7u8i  // OK
TESTE4de8         // OK
$varchar          // falso, uso de caracter `$` nao `alnum`
_cadaDele         // falso, uso de caracter `_` nao `alnum`
```

ou caso queira liberar o `_`, simplesmente: `(?=.{8,})\w+`.

Comment: Só pra acrescentar, eu faria assim `(?=.{8,})([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`, acrescentaria os parenteses para pegar o grupo.

Comment: também não lembrei do `(?i)` quando fiz minha resposta, resumindo a string para `(?i)(?=.{8,})([a-z0-9]+)`

Comment: Gostei da sua resposta `+1`. Eu acho que o AP quer forçar ter pelo menos um de cada tipo, na sua resposta casos sem maiúsculas passam. Vamos ver o que que ele quer mesmo quando ele responder/dê feedback.

Comment: Obrigado a todos, realmente precisava de mínimo 8 caracteres, uma minuscula, uma maiúscula, um número  e que aceite caracteres especiais mas não é obrigatório.

Comment: @Dorathoto devido as suas necessidades creio que a resposta correta é a do Sergio. A minha faz a validação correta mas não contempla a necessidade de um carácter de cada tipo. =D