# C# Expressão regular para string e validação de Guid

Tags: c#, regex, guid

(1). Gostaria de validar uma string, verificando se a mesma só possui {[a-z], [A-Z], [0-9], '-'}

```
if(minhaString.ContemApenas({[a-z], [A-Z], [0-9], '-'}) == true)
{
   // Minha string é válida!
}
```

(2). Preciso também validar se tal string é um Guid.

```
if(minhaString == Guid){
  // String é um Guid Válido!
}
```

Comment: Você tem a `regex` pronta e não sabe como aplicar, isso?

Comment: Aliás, acho que deveriam ser duas perguntas separadas.

Comment: Não tenho tenho a Regex, gostaria de justamente de aprender a monta-la. `ContemApenas()` foi apenas um exemplo. Coloquei na mesma pergunta pois são validações para o mesmo objeto.

Comment: Recomendo ler http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42459/express%C3%A3o-regular-n%C3%A3o-funciona-corretamente-em-webform/42486

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É bem fácil fazer as duas coisas, veja:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using static System.Console;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string str = "palavra1-2-3";
        Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$");

        bool isValid = rgx.IsMatch(str);

        WriteLine(isValid);

        //Para verificar se a string é uma Guid

        Guid result;
        bool isGuid = Guid.TryParse(str, out result);

        WriteLine(isGuid);
    }
}
```

[Veja funcionando no dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NlvXbK)
[Documentação `Guid.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

> Gostaria de validar uma string, verificando se a mesma só possui {[a-z], [A-Z], [0-9], '-'}

Pode ser feito assim:

```
var re = new Regex("[A-Za-z0-9\-]+");
var valido = re.Match("Minha String 1-2-3").Success;
```

> Preciso também validar se tal string é um `Guid`

A maneira mais rápida é assim:

```
var guidValido = PInvoke.ObjBase.CLSIDFromString(meuGuid, out valor) >= 0;
```