# está correto o teste de validade do RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex, validação, funções, senhas

estou tentando validar uma senha através do RegExp, em javascript, mas ele só retorna false quando na verdade deveria retornar true, por ter dado match no valor, alguém saberia se tem algo de errado com meu codigo?

```
    $scope.verifyPasswordIsValid = function (a , b) {
    var digits_4 = new RegExp("^(\d\d)\d{0,4}\1$");
    var seq_number = new RegExp("^1*2*3*4*3*2*1$");
    var seq_alphab = new RegExp("^a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k*l*m*n*o*p*q*r*s*t*u*v*w*x*y*z*$");

    console.log("reg alp: "+seq_alphab.test(a));
    console.log("reg 4: "+digits_4.test(a));
    console.log("reg number: "+seq_number.test(a));
}
```

Comment: Relacionado http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42459/express%C3%A3o-regular-n%C3%A3o-funciona-corretamente-em-webform/42486#42486

Comment: De exemplos das senhas que esta testando que deve estar correta e as incorretas.

Comment: para digits-4 to usando "1111", para seq_number to usando "1234", para seq_alphab to usando "abcd", ou seja para cada vez que seto, teria que retornar 2 false e um true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Percebi que o problema estava na interpretação do navegador, onde ele removia as barras "\" [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

para resolver isso é simples, é só adicionar outra barra na frente, ou seja, o codigo fica assim:

```
   $scope.verifyPasswordIsValid = function (a , b) {
var digits_4 = new RegExp("^(\\d\\d)\\d{0,4}\\1$");
var seq_number = new RegExp("^1*2*3*4*3*2*1*$");
var seq_alphab = new RegExp("^a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k*l*m*n*o*p*q*r*s*t*u*v*w*x*y*z*$");

console.log("reg alp: "+seq_alphab.test(a));
console.log("reg 4: "+digits_4.test(a));
console.log("reg number: "+seq_number.test(a));
```

}

para os sequenciais estava faltando o "*" na frente do sinal de dólar