# Regex - Expressão Regular

Tags: java, regex

Gostaria de saber por quê as expressões regulares que escrevi não estão dando *match* (casando) corretamente.

As expressões são as seguintes:

1. Nome de usuário que deve ser único e não pode conter caracteres especiais (`%-$_#@`, por exemplo), números ou espaços, com exceção de ponto final.

   Exemplo de nome de usuário válido: `jair.anderson` ou `jairanderson`
2. Senha deve ter pelo menos 8 dígitos, pelo menos 1 caractere maiúsculo e pelo menos 1 caractere não-alfabéticos (por exemplo: `!$#%`)

Expressão Regular para o nome de usuário:

```
Pattern regexUsername = Pattern.compile("[._^a-z0-9_\\._]");
```

Expressão regular para a senha:

```
Pattern regexPassword = Pattern.compile("[^!$#%].+");
```

Alguém poderia me dizer por quê não funcionam como esperado?

Comment: Como posso validar essas regras pela expressão regular? E porque tá dando errado as expressão que fiz?

Comment: Anderson, por favor, clique em [edit] abaixo da pergunta e esclareça o problema... Eu ia até incluir este último comentário seu que acho importante e também ia mudar o título para ser mais descritivo, o problema é que **não entendo** sua primeira frase, não seria *"Por algum motivo que desconheço, essa expressão NÃO valida do jeito que preciso."???*

Comment: Desculpe por não feito a pergunta de maneira mais clara, mas corrigi, vejam se conseguem entender melhor qual meu problema.

Answer (score 3):

A REGEX para o teste de nome deve ser :

```
`[a-zA-Z\.]+`
```

Assim você garante apenas letras (não acentuadas) e o `.`

Quanto a senha recomendo que seja [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42459/express%C3%A3o-regular-n%C3%A3o-funciona-corretamente-em-webform/42486#424866), mas transcrevendo a parte que lhe interessa da [resposta do @Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42459/express%C3%A3o-regular-n%C3%A3o-funciona-corretamente-em-webform/42486#answer-42471).

- `(?=.{8,})` para garantir 8 caracteres.
- `(?=.+[A-Z])` para garantir pelo menos um caractere de letra grande.
- `(?=.+[^\w])` para garantir ao menos um caractere diferente de `a-zA-Z0-9_`

Answer (score 1):

Também não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, mas o seguinte Regex atende a regra de sua senha:

```
((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$!%!]).{8,30})
```

No trecho

```
(?=.*[@#$!%!])
```

Você deve colocar entre colchetes os caracteres especiais que você pretende aceitar